# What are the user privileges required to for an ssrs report owner to 'send email'

Tags: security, ssrs, permissions

> Yes, this question is a duplicate to:
>   [SSRS - rsAccessDenied error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25491/52246) but that question is 2
>   years old and unanswered...so I thought I might try again.

Our DBA has recently departed leaving behind a number of SSRS report subscriptions to which he is (or was) the 'owner'. Based on the advise found at [Changing the SSRS Subscription Owner](http://grumpydba.blogspot.com/2012/02/changing-ssrs-subscription-owner.html) I have created a new domain account, assigned that domain account full privileges on the SSRS server (at least 'for now') and yet I am still getting the error message:

> Failure sending mail: The permissions granted to user 'DOM\NewUser'
>   are insufficient for performing this operation.Mail will not be
>   resent.

What privileges, in SSRS, SQL Server and/or Active Directory are required to allow "NewUser" to send email.

Comment: Is the new user allowed to send mail on the SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the new user allowed to send mail on the SMTP server?

You can do this:

- Review this and make sure your setup is valid with the correct user ([MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms345234%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)).
- Also check the settings in `RSreportserver.config` ([MSDNlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb630448%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)).

Comment: Indeed the problem was when the user was created in AD a corresponding email box was not set up. Once that was done the 'NewUser' was able to send mail. Unfortunately the message makes it look like a 'permissions' issue rather than a 'provisioning' issue.